# Desplegar valores como array en google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente valor que ingresa mediante un formulario de google

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero desplegarlo como si fuera un array para que quede con el la forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probe con el siguiente appscript

```
 function Desplegar() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
  var temp = ss.getRange("A2").getValue();
  ss.getRange("C2:G4").setValues(temp);
}
```

pero me dice que setValues no es un string, debo darle formato al valor de la celda o cambiar la forma de desplegarlo?

PD: se que existe la funcion split.. pero como se puede utilizar para un "array bidimensional" y que se ejecute al enviar un google form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Situación:

- Un formulario de Google envía un valor a una celda con un patrón como el siguiente:

  `[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]`
- Intentaste usar Google Apps Script para que este valor se convierta en una matriz, es decir, que cada uno de los números ocupe una celda, abarcando un intervalo de tres filas por cinco columnas
- El método `getValue()` devolvió un valor de tipo `String`. Este valor se usó como argumento del método `setValues(String)` y devolvió un error.

Análisis del Script

- El error se debe a que no existe un método `setValues` con un argumento de tipo `String`.

Observaciones

- Existe el método `setValues` que usa como argumento de tipo `Array` cuyos elementos son de tipo Array y estos a su vez cuentan con elementos de tipo `String`, `Number` o `Date`.

  - No se deben incluir elementos vacíos.
  - Todos los Arrays internos deben ser del mismo tamaño.
- Para convertir un `String` con un patrón como el mostrado arriba no es del todo conveniente usar `split` porque se usa el mismo separador para separar "filas" y "columnas", además de que requiere de algo más para eliminar los corchetes.

Propuesta de Solución

- Usar expresiones regulares, el método String.prototype.match y quizás algunas manipulaciones adicionales para afinar el resultado.

Ejemplo:

```js
// Función tomada de https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210948/1595451
function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
  index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
  var matches = [];
  var match;
  while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(match[index]);
  }
  return matches;
}

/** Caso de prueba */
var valor = '[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]';
   
/** Expresión regular que extrae el texto entre los corchetes internos */ 
var re = /\[{1}([^\[\]]*)\]{1},*/g;


var coincidencias = getMatches(valor,re);

/** Separamos cada una de las coincidencias */
var matriz = coincidencias.map(function(coincidencia){
  return coincidencia.split(',');
});

/** Para mostrar en Stack Snippet. En Google Apps Script reemplazar esta línea por una 
 * que envíe la matriz a la hoja de cálculo usando setValues
 */
console.info(matriz)
```

Notas

- Si requires saber el número de filas y columnas que ocupará la matriz, usa `matriz.length` para obtener el número de filas y `matriz[0].length` para el número de columnas.

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues

Comment: Genial! me sirvio, una consulta como hago para agregarle un contador a las filas? porque ss.getRange("C2:G4").setValues(temp); porque si el rango de filas no coincide con el getRange (G4) me tira error. y si envio un array de terminos por ejemplo [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]] me va tirar error... es decir hacerlo dinamico al lugar donde pega los valores desplegados

Comment: @MTDesigner Tomando como base el código de mi respuesta usa `matriz.length` para el número de filas y `matriz[0].length` para el número de columnas. Si requieres mayor orientación publica una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Si eso necesitaba, muchas gracias!